# split string update numbers only

Tags: python, string, return, addition, updates

I have a function using raw_input getting a sentence from user.  Then my second function splits the sentence so I am only trying to update the numbers on the sentence.  This is the split sentence:

```
['You', 'are', '42', 'this',  'year']
```

I am trying to update 42 to 43 do a return and print 'You are 43 this year'

I am able to pull the number by using isdigit() but I can't increase it. This is what I have so far:

```
def GetDigits(sentence):
    for i in sentence:
        if i.isindigit():
           i = i +1
    return sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add 1 to a string, as `'42'` isn't the same as `42`.

You need to change `'42'` to an `int` first using `int(v)`, then increase it.

```
def GetDigits(sentence):
    for i, v in enumerate(sentence):
        if v.isdigit():
           sentence[i] = str(int(v) + 1)
    return sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in method for strings that would be much better for this, `format()`

```
age = raw_input('How old are you?')
sentence = 'You are {} this year'
print(sentence.format(age))
```

If you need to update it you can:

```
print(sentence.format(int(age) + 1))
```

Alternatively as function utilizing a generator comprehension:

```
def get_digits(sentence):
    return ' '.join(str(int(word) + 1) if word.isdigit() else word for word in sentence.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in Python are immutable objects, so when you do `i = i+1`, you are creating a new object. This new object is not part of your original `sentence` object. Also, '42' is a string. You can't apply numeric add operation on it. You need to convert it to an integer first.

This is what you need -

```
def GetDigits(sentence):
    for idx, value in enumerate(sentence):
        if value.isdigit():
           sentence[idx] = int(value) +1
    return sentence
```

Comment: Cool. You should accept one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The key issue here is that you're trying to find a function that lets you know when it's safe/correct to convert a string to an int—but there is no such function. There are various approximations, but the simplest thing to do is just try to convert the string. This is a general principle in Python, [EAFP: Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). The language has been designed around the fact that the way to check whether something will work is to just do it, then handle the case where it didn't work (normally meaning an exception). Trying to fight that design is just going to make your life harder.

But that's not the only issue; there are multiple problems here.

- `isindigit` isn't a method of strings. Maybe you meant `isdigit`?
- `isdigit` doesn't give you the right answer for, say, `-3`—or, for that matter, integers in non-Western scripts (which may return true for `isdigit` but not actually be interpretable as integers by Python).
- Just because `i` is a string representing an integer doesn't mean it's an integer; it's still a string, and `i + 1` is still a `TypeError`. You need to call `int(i)` to get its value as a number.
- Just reassigning to `i` doesn't affect `sentence` at all. All you're doing is making the local variable `i` into a name for a different value. You need to *do* something with that `i`—either build a new sentence, or modify the sentence in-place (e.g., by using `enumerate` to keep track of the index, so you can do `sentence[index] = …`).
- While it isn't clear what you're doing with the results, I'll bet you actually want to get strings back, not a mix of strings and integers, so you'll probably want to convert back to `str` after adding 1.

So, what you want is something like this:

```
def GetDigits(sentence):
    new_sentence = []
    for i in sentence:
        try:
            i = str(int(i) + 1)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        new_sentence.append(i)
    return new_sentence
```

However, this might be a little too clever as written. If `i` doesn't represent an integer, `int(i)` will raise a `ValueError`, meaning `i` is still referring to the original string, which we add to `new_sentence`. Otherwise, we'll convert it to an integer, add 1, convert back to a string, and make `i` refer to this new string, which we add to `new_sentence`. If you don't understand why `new_sentence.append(i)` always does the right thing, you should rewrite it more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky way through regex using `re` module,

```
import re
sentence = input("Enter the sentence : \n")
def GetDigits(sentence):
    L = []
    for i in sentence.split():
        if re.match(r'\d+$', i):
            i = int(i)+1
            L.append(str(i))
        else:
            L.append(i)
    sentence = ' '.join(L)
    return(sentence)
print(GetDigits(sentence))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the sentence : 
You are 42 this year
You are 43 this year
```

Comment: What does using the regex add here? And why use `$` but not `^`? Are you trying to make it so `-23` matches? If so, you need `search` instead of `match`—and then you also need to deal with the fact that `a23` also matches, but will raise an exception.